# How AzureAD knows that device is registered or not?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, mdm, intune

We are trying to clear some things on conditional access using intune and azureAD. I have enrolled my device with intune and also pushed Microsoft team app using play store account in my device.
When i trying to login into microsoft teams using AzureAD, how AzureAD is getting device related information and using that information decision will be taken.
so basically we want to know data flow between azureAD, device and intune at the time of login.

Answer (score 0):

So to summarize in a statement, conditional access policies are ANDed i.e. it enforces policies in 2 steps and if all the conditions are not satisfied, the block takes precedence and the user/device needs to satisfy all the conditions set forth to get access to the app/online service to which the device/user has requested.Refer to the below article for more insights

https://www.vansurksum.com/2020/05/25/may-2020-update-of-the-conditional-access-demystified-whitepaper-workflow-cheat-sheet-implementation-workflow-and-documentation-spreadsheet/